# Inserting an item to a linked list - is iteration necessary (C)?

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm currently studying linked lists for interview prep, would appreciate if anybody could shed some light on this. The following function in C supposedly inserts a new element into the list after a certain Element elem (passed as an argument to the function):

```
bool insertAfter(Element * elem, int data){

    Element * newElem, * curPos = head;
    newElem->data = data;

    while(curPos){
        if(curPos == elem){
            newElem->next = curPos->next;
            curPos->next = newElem;
            return true;
        }
        curPos = curPos->Next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Although the above is specified in the textbook I am studying from, I tried coming up with a solution that does not use any iteration whatsoever:

```
bool insertAfter(Element * elem, int data){
    Element * newElem;
    newElem->next = elem->next
    newElem->data = data
    elem->next = newElem;
    return true;
}
```

However, as it appears too simplistic, I sense that it may not work, but am not sure why. I need some insights on the technicalities on why this may or may not work, thanks.

Comment: `newElem` is uninitialized.

Comment: You are inserting to a linked list without using head.You can use recursion instead of iteration.

Comment: Iteration is necessary as you need link of the element after which you want to add new element .Your program is adding the element in the beginning and without even re-locating the head pointer .Hence it is useless .

Comment: You can only insert a new first node (or last node in a doubly-linked list) without iterating (or recursing). If you want to insert after a specific existing node, you will have to move through the list to find that node. As a follow-on to BLUEPIXY, since you declare a pointer `newElem`, you need to *allocate* space for the node before you assign data to it or insert it into the list.

Comment: The first version of `insertAfter` checks that `elem` is actually in the list before going ahead with the insert, whereas yours doesn't... but yours is a better design

Comment: Please indicate the book and where that snippet can be found: as it gives the example of not initialising newElem, it may be a book to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions suffer from the error of using `newElem` as though it were a valid pointer. It is not. It is not initialized to point to valid object.

You can correct that by allocating memory for an object before using:

```
Element * newElem = malloc(sizeof(*newElem));
```

The difference between the two versions is that if `elem` is not accessible from `head` for some reason or it is `NULL`, the first version will do nothing to the existing list. The second version does not deal with either of those scenarios. It assumes that `elem` is in the list and that it is not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because you do not know your `newElem`. In linked list you have knowledge about a head and each element gives you information where to find the next one:

```
head -> e1 -> e2 -> ...
```

So you need to iterate till you will find the element you care about. But you can also iterate with the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic will work, because you just need a pointer to a node where you want to insert a node. If you already have such a pointer, no need to iterate and search for the node.

However the search (iteration) would be relevant if do not have in hand the node pointer where you want to insert the new node. Example: suppose the nodes have unique keys and you do not have the node pointer where the key exists and you want to insert after you find  the node containing the specific key, then you need to find the correct node pointer and do the insertion (The function should then take in key as the argument).

However in your code (both cases), you have not allocated the memory for the new node. You need to do `malloc` for the new node and then go on with the insertion.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is pretty much correct. The iteration in the example is almost completely useless.

What the example function is doing is: given an element to insert the new data after, it looks through the list starting with `head` to find *that same element*, then inserts the data - doing nothing with `head` or `elem` after finding it. Since all the loop does is "find" an element to which you already had a pointer, it essentially did nothing at all and is useless.

The only possible use of this is to constrain the insertion function to only work on this one list beginning with `head`, globally, throughout your program. This is such a strange design decision that one would likely assume it's a mistake unless given a reason to believe otherwise (dynamic data structures constrained to a single instance are an unusual pattern; more importantly, the *whole point* of linked lists is O(1) insertion, which the example function breaks by adding this useless loop). `head` is not needed for any other reason than to enforce this constraint, and if this *is* desired, it would make more sense to pass it in as a parameter as well so that the function is able to be used on more than one list per-program. (Or, not to perform the check at all: another use of linked lists is that you can pass around and insert after nodes *without* worrying about the head element.)

As other people have pointed out, you fail to actually allocate `newElem`, but so does the textbook. Overall, it's a rubbish example; not only did the author make a mistake with allocation, but they don't appear to understand the basic advantages of using linked lists. You should definitely treat this textbook with suspicion.